# When #movingtogitlab: Is there a possibility to set all imported projects to public?

Tags: git, gitlab

I tried #movingtogitlab (https://about.gitlab.com/2018/06/03/movingtogitlab/). When importing Github repositories into Gitlab, is there an option to specify if these repositories should be public or private? Or is there a possibility to change them all to public without clicking into the settings of each project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many projects you are importing, the fastest way would be to use a framework and write a short script to change the visibility.

https://about.gitlab.com/applications/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea. I did not recognice that it could be as easy as that^^ I will now: 1. Import all repos (private) 2. List all repos via https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-user-projects and 3. Update every repo to public with: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#edit-project

Comment: I will provide a project link here as soon as I have finished the solution. Will be a small script in Python probably.

Comment: Ok, it's finally done: https://github.com/SeppPenner/GitlabVisibilitySetter Have fun, for me it worked, you can check the result here if you like: https://gitlab.com/users/SeppPenner/projects

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a way. Here is what [the GitHub import documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html#overview) says about project visibility:

> References to pull requests and issues are preserved (GitLab.com & 8.7+), and each imported repository maintains visibility level unless that [visibility level is restricted](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html#restricting-the-use-of-public-or-internal-projects), in which case it defaults to the default project visibility.

It doesn’t mention such a feature, and it doesn’t mention visibility anywhere else.

Here is the documentation on [changing a project’s visibility](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html#how-to-change-project-visibility) (not specific to imported projects):

> #### How to change project visibility
>
> 1. Go to your project's **Settings**
> 2. Change "Visibility Level" to either Public, Internal or Private

It doesn’t mention any bulk visibility-changing feature either.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I already found out. I was just curious if it's somehow possible.